# d3.js pie chart - legend toggle

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a d3.js pie chart application. I am trying to develop the functionality that when you click on the legend rectangles, it toggles the slice on/off as well as the fill inside the legend rectangle.

Although there is a bug with an undefined function - but I am not sure why this error is occurring as the function is defined.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3261/

```
this.piedata = methods.pie(dataSet);
console.log("animate slice2", this.piedata);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line (233) has turned your `currentDataSet` from an `Array` into an `Object`:

```
var currentDataSet = jQuery.extend(true, {}, methods.currentDataSet);
```

`d3` then complains when it tries to call the `map` function on `currentDataSet` as it is expecting an array.

You need to change it to take an Array as the second parameter:

```
var currentDataSet = jQuery.extend(true, [], methods.currentDataSet);
```

Comment: Great that did it man. How do I fix the toggle function so it can properly show the toggled areas - maybe I should get a copy of the last data set instead - http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3267/